# Registration SignUp into my android app

Tags: android, registration

I need to do a registration signup into my android application.So far I done it like this:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText mName;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mAge;
    private Button mSubmit;

    // Form used for validation
    private Form mForm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initFields();
        initValidationForm();
        initCallbacks();
    }



    private void initFields() {
        mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    }

    private void initValidationForm() {
        mForm = new Form(this);
        mForm.addField(Field.using(mName).validate(NotEmpty.build(this)));
        mForm.addField(Field.using(mEmail).validate(NotEmpty.build(this)).validate(IsEmail.build(this)));
        mForm.addField(Field.using(mAge).validate(InRange.build(this, 0, 120)));
    }

    private void initCallbacks() {
        mAge.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    submit();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submit();
            }
        });
    }

    private void submit() {
        FormUtils.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this, mAge);
        if (mForm.isValid()) {
         //   Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sample_activity_form_is_valid), Style.CONFIRM).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sample_activity_form_is_valid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } 

 }
```

I couldn't able to get an exact registration sign up(Name,email,password,Re-enter password) for android login.Anybody can help me with this.If I get some tutorial or source code related to this.its enough for me.Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? code appears ok, though it seems you are using a number of libraries, and we don't have your XML... Anyway a quick Google search for 'android login tutorial' would be appropriate here

Comment: where do you want to save the login credentials??Do you maintain any server database??

Comment: @micky no I didn't maintain server database

Comment: ok for checking login details you need to store the signup details know???where you want to store them???

Comment: which database ???you meant sqlite??

Comment: yes.I need to use sqlite to store it. @micky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First know, for any registration you have to maintain the database where you can store your login credentials to check back.

Here are two links, which uses the sqlite database for storing and retreiving the signup details.

1.[android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example](http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/)

2.[android-code-for-user-registration](http://androidtipsbynama.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-code-for-user-registration-and.html)

If you want to use mysql database for your registration you need to know json parsing.

Thanks